# how can i set space between divs?

Tags: html, css

this is my html/css code:
[JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/8nW7V/)

how can i set space between

```
nav id="section-navi"
section class="section" 
div id="footer-main"
```

Comment: Have you tried adding margins to them? Remember that <nav> and <section> are html5 elements and are ignored by old browsers. (I believe even up to IE8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add "margin-bottom" property to the CSS #section-navi, and "margin-top" to #footer-main. please see below.

```
#section-navi
{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
margin: 10px auto 0px;
min-height: 40px;
padding: 45px 24px 0;
position: relative;
width: 938px;
z-index: 4;
}
#footer-main
{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box #21242C;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
height: 75px;
margin-top: -10px;
padding: 0 24px;
position: relative;
width: 938px;
margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

HTML:

```
 <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cleaner { clear:both; }
.h20 { height: 20px; }
```

Here is another version of your JSFiddle with the changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/T6md9/1/